# Dropping buffer when writing custom Vec

Tags: vector, rust, memory-management

Reading the `rustonomicon`, I found this implementation of a custom `Vec<T>`.

```
pub struct IntoIter<T> {
    buf: NonNull<T>,
    cap: usize,
    start: *const T,
    end: *const T,
    _marker: PhantomData<T>,
}
```

and it's `impl` of `IntoIterator`

```
impl<T> IntoIterator for Vec<T> {
    type Item = T;
    type IntoIter = IntoIter<T>;
    fn into_iter(self) -> IntoIter<T> {
        // Can't destructure Vec since it's Drop
        let ptr = self.ptr;
        let cap = self.cap;
        let len = self.len;

        // Make sure not to drop Vec since that would free the buffer
        mem::forget(self);

        unsafe {
            IntoIter {
                buf: ptr,
                cap: cap,
                start: ptr.as_ptr(),
                end: if cap == 0 {
                    // can't offset off this pointer, it's not allocated!
                    ptr.as_ptr()
                } else {
                    ptr.as_ptr().add(len)
                },
                _marker: PhantomData,
            }
        }
    }
}
```

I want to ask about this specific line:

```
// Make sure not to drop Vec since that would free the buffer
mem::forget(self);
```

In which case the buffer could be freed? More specificaly, in that piece of code.

Or could be released in another implementation and, when called first, clean the buff and then, with the buff freed, generate a `use-after-free` error?

Would be enought to just `mem::forget(self.buf)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Without the `forget`, the `self` object would be dropped when that function returns, and its `drop` method will be called. The drop implementation would then free the buffer, which is *not* what we want, because the `IntoIter` is using it.

Using `forget`, we get rid of the `self` object without running its `drop` function, letting the `IntoIter` object semantically take ownership of the buffer, use it, and free it when it's done using it.

Comment: But, self, as a value on the parameter, is still consumed with the call over `self`?

Comment: @NotJungler'sFault Well, yes. `self` is still subject to the usual rules of objects - it's not that special. Consider if the method added `self` to a list that was passed in or a global - it would be "recoverable" and would need to be dropped.